# How to join 2 tables with group by query using laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

i have a users and chats table in my database. Here are some sample data in my tables:

users table:

```
id  |   name  |    avatar
1       john     default.png
2       mark       picture.jpg
```

chats table:

```
   id  |   user_id  |  friend_id | message | status
    1        1           2           hello     0
    2        1           2           hi        1
```

the purpose of the status column is to determine whether the message is already read.

```
  status 0 = unread message
  status 1 = read message
```

Here is my code to group and count all the unread messages:

```
        $chat = DB::table('chats')
             ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'chats.user_id')
             ->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->where('friend_id', Auth::user()->id)
             ->where('status',0)
             ->groupBy('user_id')
             ->get();
```

Here is my code when i tried to insert the users avatar but i get this error: `users.avatar' isn't in GROUP BY`

```
        $chat = DB::table('chats')
             ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'chats.user_id')
             ->select('users.avatar','user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->where('admin_id', Auth::user()->id)
             ->where('status',2)
             ->groupBy('user_id')
             ->get();
```

What i want is to also get the avatar of the user who sent the messages. I don not know how to structure my query to get the avatar column. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Off the top of my head, did you try adding `'users.avatar'` to your `select(...)` list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `GROUP BY` the `id` in the `users` table, you should be able to select any other column in the `users` table as well:

```
$chat = DB::table('chats')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'chats.user_id')
         ->select('users.id', 'users.avatar', DB::raw('COUNT(*) AS total'))
         ->where('friend_id', Auth::user()->id)
         ->where('status',0)
         ->groupBy('users.id')
         ->get();
```

At first site, this might seem to be a violation of the rules of `GROUP BY`, which state that non aggregate columns cannot be selected.  But this is allowed because the user `id` functionally determines the values of the other columns.  In other words, if we select a user `id`, we know precisely what his avatar value must be.

If the above gives you an error, you may try this `GROUP BY`:

```
->groupBy('users.id', 'users.avatar')
```

Comment: i get this error when i tried your code - Syntax error or access violation: users.avatar' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: You may use `DB::raw('MAX(users.avatar) AS avatar')`, but you should not be getting an error.

Comment: Thanks. in my config\database.php i changed the 'strict' in the mysql array to false and it worked!